# How to get the contents appear within the the CDATA in XML?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

```
<EventDays>
    <EventDaysInfo year = "2012" month = "0">
    <![CDATA[<Days day="0" name="sdfds" desc="fgfds"  _img=""/>]]>
    <![CDATA[<Days day="0" name="sdf" desc=""  _img=""/>]]>
    <![CDATA[<Days day="0" name="dsf" desc="dsfd"  _img=""/>]]>
        .....
        .....
```

This is the structure of my XML, and I tried in some ways, but I can't able to get Character DATA as XML data.

Is this any way to convert CDATA into XML in AS3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you're using CDATA completely wrong. it's telling the parser that the following content doesn't contain markup (within the `nodeValue`), like this:

```
<node attr="abc"><![CDATA[here is line 1<br/>and a linebreak and btw 1 > 0]]></node>
```

otherwise the parser would think that the `<br/>` or the `>` belong to the xml structure...
and i think you can only have 1 CDATA-part per node.

in your case you could just remove all the CDATAs.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <EventDays>
            <EventDaysInfo year = "2012" month = "0">
                <![CDATA[<Days day="0" name="sdfds" desc="fgfds"  _img=""/>]]>
                <![CDATA[<Days day="0" name="sdf" desc=""  _img=""/>]]>
                <![CDATA[<Days day="0" name="dsf" desc="dsfd"  _img=""/>]]>
            </EventDaysInfo>
        </EventDays>


<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        protected function XML_NameReader():void
        {

            var xml:XML=new XML("<root>"+XML_Name.EventDaysInfo+"</root>")
            Alert.show(xml.children().toString());
            Alert.show(xml.children()[0].toXMLString());
            Alert.show(xml.children()[0].@name.toString());
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Try this code. the XML_Name is the xml name